# Method Not Displaying Properly

Tags: java

The method "aboveAverage" in the following code is not displaying correctly and I've tried everything I can. Could someone please explain what's going wrong?

My code:

```
import java.util.*;
public class DailyCatch
{
  private int fishermanID, fisherID;
  private String dateOfSample, date;
  private double[] fishCaught = new double[10];
  private int currWeight = 0;
  private String summary;
  private double average;
  private int aboveAvg;

  public DailyCatch() {  }

  public DailyCatch (int fishermanID, String dateOfSample)
  {
    fisherID = fishermanID;
    date = dateOfSample;
  }

  public DailyCatch (int fishermanID, String dateOfSample, String weight)
  {
    this(fishermanID, dateOfSample);
    readWeights(weight);
  }

  public void addFish(double weight)
  {
    if (currWeight > 10)
    {
       // array full
    }
    else
    {
      fishCaught[currWeight] = weight;
      currWeight += 1;  // update current index of array
    }
  }

  private void readWeights(String weightsAsString) 
  {
    String[] weightsRead = weightsAsString.split("\\s+");
    for (int i = 0; i < weightsRead.length; i++) 
    {
       this.addFish(Double.parseDouble(weightsRead[i]));
    }
  } 

  public String toString()
  {
    return "Fisherman ID: " + fisherID + "\nDate:" + date + "\nFish Caught with Weights: " + Arrays.toString(fishCaught);
  }

  public void printWeights()
  {
     for (int i = 0; i < fishCaught.length; i++)
     {
          System.out.println(fishCaught[i]);
     } 
  }

  public double averageWeight()
  {
      double sum = 0;
     double count = 0;
     for (int i = 0; i < fishCaught.length; i++)
     {
          if (fishCaught[i] != 0)
          {
                  sum += fishCaught[i];
              count += 1;
                  average = sum/count;
          }
 }
  return average;
   }

    public String getSummary()
{   int storyTellerCount = 0;
    int keeperCount = 0;
    int throwBackCount = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < fishCaught.length; i++)
    {
        if (fishCaught[i] > 5)
        {
            storyTellerCount++;
        }

        else if (fishCaught[i] >=1 && fishCaught[i] <= 5)
        {
            keeperCount++;
        }

        else if (fishCaught[i] < 1 && fishCaught[i] > 0)
        {
            throwBackCount++;
        }

    }  String summary = ("\nStoryteller - " + storyTellerCount+ "\nKeeper - " + keeperCount + "\nThrowback - " + throwBackCount);

        return summary;
}

public int aboveAverage()
{   
    int greatAvgCount = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < fishCaught.length; i++)
    {
        if (fishCaught[i] > average)
        {
            aboveAvg = greatAvgCount++;
        }
    }
    return aboveAvg;
}   

}
```

Test Code:

```
public class BigBass
{
public static void main (String[]args)
{
//Part 1
DailyCatch monday1 = new DailyCatch(32, "4/1/2013", "4.1 5.5 2.3 0.5 4.8 1.5");
System.out.println(monday1);

//Part 2
DailyCatch monday2 = new DailyCatch(44, "4/1/2013");
System.out.println(monday2);
monday2.addFish(2.1);
monday2.addFish(4.2);
System.out.println(monday2);

//Part 3
System.out.println("\n\nSUMMARY OF FISHERMAN 32");
System.out.println(monday1.getSummary());

//Part 4
double avg = monday1.averageWeight();
System.out.printf("\nThere are %d fish above the average weight of %.1f.", monday1.aboveAverage(), avg);
}
}
```

I just need to get Part 4 to work here. What it does is return that there have been 2 fish caught that are above average when I know it should be 3. The average is 3.1.

Comment: Have you tried stepping through it with a debugger? Have you tried println() statements in the aboveAverage() method? Those would always be the first things I would try.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple mistake.

```
public int aboveAverage() {   
    int greatAvgCount = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < fishCaught.length; i++) {
        if (fishCaught[i] > 3.1) {
            greatAvgCount++; // no 'return'
        }
    }
    return greatAvgCount;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (fishCaught[i] > 3.1)
        {
            return greatAvgCount++;
        }

First try : 4.1 > 3.1
```

true
`returns 0 ++` which is 0 basically

You can increment the counter inside the loop and keep the return statement for the end only.

Answer (score 0):

This line is your problem,

```
return greatAvgCount++;
```

you are incrimenting greatAvgCount then returning its initial value, there should be no "return" on this line

The aboveAverage method should be

```
public int aboveAverage()
{   
    int greatAvgCount = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < fishCaught.length; i++)
    {
        if (fishCaught[i] > 3.1)
        {
            greatAvgCount++;
        }
    }
    return greatAvgCount;
}
```

Also, you may just be doing it for debug, in which case fair enough, but hardcoding the "average" as 3.1 is generally considered bad practice. If you want average to be always 3.1 (i.e. its a global average that you've looked up from a book then its more usual to declare a static variable called `double AVERAGE=3.1` and then use that where ever average is required, that way if the "book value" changes you only need to change average in one place in your code. If average is calculated from your data obviously you should use the calculated value.

Also not directly related to your problem but why are you using an array for your caught fish with a predefined maximum of 10. If you used an ArrayList you could add to it as you saw fit and it would auto expand to accommodate

```
private double[] fishCaught = new double[10];
```

becomes

```
private ArrayList<Double> fishCaught = new ArrayList<Double>();
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
public int aboveAverage() {   
    int greatAvgCount = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < fishCaught.length; i++) {
        if (fishCaught[i] > 3.1) {
            greatAvgCount++;
        }
    }
    return greatAvgCount;
}
```